How to prevent update using other disks
I had Ubuntu installed on my SSD. My Ubuntu was asking for updates, but during the update, it seemed to save the downloaded files on an old hard disk that I use for non-essential files like music. The system crashed during the update due to bad sectors on the secondary disk, and it wouldn't working at all. I have reinstalled Ubuntu now.
How can I change the settings to prevent the OS from using my secondary disk?
P.S: I know system update will eventually replace specific files in specific address, but it seems it uses my HDD as cache during update.

Depends upon how you originally set up your system to permit the OS to use multiple disks. Please edit your question to show that to us.

The system will update specific files in specific directories; your control is what sources you are using (ie. where your packages come from; if from a trusted source they'll only update in system directories; if however you've added untrustworthy sources they do have access to your file-system!) and your control of what drive directories are placed on (ie. usually controlled by file-system table).  If you have updates occurring on multiple drives then it's how you setup the system at install OR changes you made post-install; so amend your choices.

You've provided no specific Ubuntu product & release details; ie. we don't know if you're using Ubuntu Core 20, Ubuntu Desktop 24.10, Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS etc, so we can't provide specifics. My prior comment is your best clue, ie. the system will use set directories determined by your setup, especially details from your file-system table.  The command you used however matters; eg. if you wget files prior to dpkg or snap install; then your $PWD will control where the file was placed at download time... Most of your control is via file system table as already said.

Hi @guiverc, thank you for your time. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and using graphical app (software updater) which is installed with Ubuntu. I think it uses apt.
